# JQuery Dialog modal option not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="dialog" title="lala" style="display:none;">
        <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

This is the JavaScript

```
$bb('#addTopicButton').live('click',function() {

     $bb( "#dialog" ).dialog({ modal:true, closeOnEscape: false, draggable:false, resizable:false }); 

       });
```

Why modal is not working? When it is opened I still can click other links on the page and do things in the background.

Thanks a lot

**UPDATE:**
It seems to be working though. Only the links are active in the background and working. How can I disable everything, including links?

Comment: Do you have the relevant CSS files in the right place? As I recall, modal works by placing an overlay behind the dialog which prevents the user from clicking anything else. This overlay requires certain CSS to work.

Comment: I have no css, where/how should I define it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You probably just need to include the jQuery UI CSS to your page.

Google has this on its CDN here:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

The modal option on the dialog creates an overlay under your dialog but over the rest of the content. This overlay needs the jQuery UI CSS to function correctly.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot, brilliant, don't know how I could forget about it

Comment: Its easy, I do that all the time. Spent an hour trying to get jquery to work the other day on a new page and had forgot to include jquery

Answer (score 22):

Just had the same issue. I needed the CSS, but I didn't want all of it. So I just copy pasted this part in my own CSS code:

```
.ui-widget-overlay { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: #aaaaaa;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the necessary part of the .css file out :)

Comment: Amazing!! I feel dumb for not thinking about this earlier :P

Answer (score 15):

Adding only .ui-widget-overlay to your css will make the overlay appear on the complete top, and even the dialog will be unusable.

Therefore, the .ui-front class too should be added:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.ui-front {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Much better in my case than including the whole base styles from jQ-UI. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I solved it in nearly the same way I went into the 'jquery-ui.theme.css' file searched for '.ui-widget-overlay' and changed the block from:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    background: #A9BCD0;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=100); /* support: IE8 */
}
```

to

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    background: #A9BCD0;
    opacity: .3;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=30); /* support: IE8 */
}
```